# Scroll offset function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, scroll

I have recently added a window.matchMedia function to allow me to run different javascript functions based on different media queries. The issue I am running into is the following scroll function will not work anymore:

```
var oTop = $('#home-img-block-section').offset().top - window.innerHeight;
 $(window).scroll(function() {

var pTop = $('body').scrollTop();
console.log(pTop + ' - ' + oTop);
if (pTop > oTop) {
  imgDelays();
  imgDelaysSlide();
}
```

I have tried:

```
 if (pTop > oTop) {
  imgDelays() && imgDelaysSlide();
}
```

But it did not help.

I am running this same scroll function throughout my site and it works great. It just won't work with this new function I have added for some reason. You can see in the snippet ( I will add a jsfiddle in a comment as it is easier to see this ) that when you scroll down to the green section, the three blocks are already there. The delays and fadeIn's work, they just don't wait until you are at the scroll point. However, this does work for my 640px or less media query, this function imgDelaysSlide();. Why won't the scroll function work for the imgDelays() function?

```js
$(function() {
  var oTop = $('#home-img-block-section').offset().top - window.innerHeight;
  $(window).scroll(function() {

    var pTop = $('body').scrollTop();
    console.log(pTop + ' - ' + oTop);
    if (pTop > oTop) {
      imgDelays();
      imgDelaysSlide();
    }
  });
});

function imgDelays() {
  $('.fadeBlock1').delay(300).fadeIn(500);
  $('.fadeBlock2').delay(800).fadeIn(500);
  $('.fadeBlock3').delay(1300).fadeIn(500);
}

function imgDelaysSlide() {
  $('.fadeBlock1').delay(300).animate({
    'left': '0%'
  }, 700);
  $('.fadeBlock2').delay(800).animate({
    'left': '0%'
  }, 700);
  $('.fadeBlock3').delay(1300).animate({
    'left': '0%'
  }, 700);
}
var mq = window.matchMedia('@media all and (max-width: 640px)');
if (mq.matches) {
  imgDelaysSlide();
} else {
  imgDelays();
}
```

```css
#blue {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: blue;
}
#red {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: red;
}
#home-img-block-section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: green;
}
.block {
  width: 33.33%;
  float: left;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.block img {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
@media screen and (max-width:640px) {
.block {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
left: -110%;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="blue"></div>
<div id="red"></div>
<div id="home-img-block-section">
  <div class="block fadeBlock1"><img src="http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/emt725/SqToAcuteTri/Square.gif"></div>
  <div class="block fadeBlock2"><img src="http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/emt725/SqToAcuteTri/Square.gif"></div>
  <div class="block fadeBlock3"><img src="http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/emt725/SqToAcuteTri/Square.gif"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=tqB1t4f33M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like we discussed over the collab jsfiddle, we just needed to prevent your function from triggering on page load when the width is above 640px.

```
if (mq.matches) {
  imgDelaysSlide();
} else {
  //imgDelays();
```

You can keep the bunny :D

Comment: Thanks again for the help!